# Making an activity which started itself go back to previous screen with "onBackPressed()"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, parameters

I have an activity which is repeated "x" times with this piece of code :

```
//create intent to start itself again with different parameters
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_ID, temp.getCat_ID());
            intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_SHOPID, temp.getShopID());
            intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_SITEID, temp.getSiteID());
            intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_NAME, temp.getCat_Name());

            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
```

My goal is that when the user presses the back button that the same activity gets started  as there was before with the same parameters as before and such. I tried saving them in an Activity ArrayList but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call finish, your activity will end.
When you don't call finish, your activity just go to the background. In that case, when you press the backbutton in your new activity, your previous activity comes up.

I think when you just delete finish(), it will work.

Comment: However what do you exactly mean with, repeated "x" times?

Comment: that it is unknown at compiling time how many activities there are

Comment: in that case deleting finish() will work, you will receive your last activity when you press back. I fyou keep finish, you will exit your application once you press back.

Comment: Man. I´ve been struggling with this trying all kinds of weird methods but this seemed to do it. Thanks, upvote my question and i´ll accept-upvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

It's okay if you save the parameters you've already set earlier, but you need to retrieve all that information from the `Intent` itself and repopulate your activity with the proper data.

This must be done like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra(CATEGORY_ID);

    // retrieve the others and populate your activity 

}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to pass the parameters or retrieve them though. I'll add my getIds() method to show

Answer (score 0):

in your activity, get event back

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
        // and you have to make a intent to call this activity again with parameter other
        finish(); // and call finish() here to close the old activity
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

hope this help!

Comment: is there any way to use the savedInstanceState for the app to remember the values of that specific instsance of the activity?

Comment: no, source code like this, in your activity <pre>@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
        // and you have to make a intent to call this activity again with parameter other
        finish(); // and call finish() here to close the old activity
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
} <code>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the onBackPressed method?

Comment: Yes I have but I want to go back to the previous version of the same activity without having to load and/or make HTTP requests all over again

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use the same activity?

Comment: Yes. My app retrieves data from a SOAP service which gives back different categories from a webshop. And because different categories have different number of layers (computers - desktop - gaming vs. printers - 3d - products) I call the same activity again each time

Comment: But you can use fragments, stack them and use the FragmentManager to handle the stacking for you when back button is pressed

Comment: but  wouldn't fragments just take care of the UI. I have buttons let's say which represent object with specific Ids for requests for my calls. Would a fragment manager also pass the values or just take care of my UI?

Comment: Can you explain me in more detail which is the scenario in your activity? You have buttons and when you press them you make a call, is that right? And when you receive back the info you update the UI with new buttons

Comment: Yes. correctly. Those buttons represent the names of certain categories in a webshop and every time you press a button you go deeper into the "tree" of categories until you reach a product(s). Therefore I need to restart my activity with the parameters retrieved from the pressed button and if the user presses the back button I want it to go to the previous "layer"

Comment: Imagine you have your activity and you load the info into the first fragment as soon as you have the new info you can replace the current fragment with a new one (instance of the same Fragment class) with other information and so on. The activity will handle the back pressed